# Running vs moving car?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning

> 1. After many failed attempts, I finally managed to put on some lipstick in a **moving** car.
> 2. After many failed attempts, I finally managed to put on some lipstick in a **running** car.

Which verb should be used here? And why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that the *failed attempts* consisted of red smears over your face, you now managed to apply lipstick in a **moving** car.

A **running** car is either a car that is *not broken* or one whose engine is switched on right now, but does not mean that it is *in motion* when you pull out your lipstick.